# Inherit class from page, usercontrol, and masterpage

Tags: asp.net

I have `Page`, `MasterPage` and `UserControl` in my project.

So I create `basepage` class and share some logic, then inherit from System.Web.UI.Page. My problem is I want use single basePage for any type of UI content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not inherit from multiple base classes in .NET, so you can not do what you are looking at here.

However, you probably do not need to do it. `Page`, `MasterPage` and `UserControl` can all access the currently rendering `Page` and `MasterPage` instances via properties. You can then test their actual types and cast them appropriately, to gain access to the common code you need.